# Looking for application that captures name-card and sync with google contact?

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account, nexus-one, photos

I'm looking for an Android application that `captures picture of name-card` and can help to `sync with Google contact` the contact information in that captured image.

If you know one, please share.

ps.

I'm using Nexus One phone.

Answer (score 2):

You could give [CamCard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.intsig.BCRLite&hl=en) a try.

> CamCard is a professional business card reader and business card
>   scanner. Simply take a picture of a business card, CamCard recognizes
>   the business card and saves contact information in Card Holder or your
>   Address Book. Then feel at ease to manage cards with CamCard -
>   business card reader and business card scanner.

Of course, you can always sync Google contacts.

Answer (score 2):

Google Goggles had this feature [enabled](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=258341aeb47a345a&hl=en) last year.